# Ordered set and minimal element

Tags: order-theory

> Consider the set $A=\{n\in\mathbb{N} \mid n\geq 2\}.$ Let $A\times A$ be an ordered set defined by: $(a,b)\preceq (c,d)$ iff $a\mid c$ and $b\leq d$. I have proved that there is no maximal, greatest, first element.

---

Now I'm trying to find how much minimal elements there are. I think that there are infinite number of minimal elements but don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Can you find one minimal element?  Can you find a second?  You are correct that there are an infinite number of minimal elements.  A good way here is to describe the minimal elements and note that there are an infinite number meeting the description.

Comment: @RossMillikan I can't find the pattern

Comment: What minimal elements did you find?

Answer (score 1):

Note that all minimal elements must have $2$ in the second place, as $(a,2) \prec (a,b)$ for $b \gt 2$.  What $c$ do not have numbers that divide them?

Added:  the minimal elements will be all pairs of the form $(p,2)$ for $p$ a prime.  These will be minimal because any $(a,b) \preceq (p,2)$ must have $a|p$ so $a=p$ and $b \le 2$ so $b=2$.  Any other $(a,b)$ will not be minimal because either $a$ will have a proper divisor or there will be a number strictly less than $b$.  In either case there will be a pair that is strictly less.

Comment: why there must be 2?

Comment: Are you asking why there must be a $2$ in the second place?  That is just what I was explaining.  Otherwise, what did you mean?